# WebApi, Custom model binder and Data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

So, is it possible to combine the 3?

When I send a request to the server that does not conform to the model annotated validation (empty email in this case) ModelState.IsValid is true.

**Model**

```
public class UpdateModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Binder**

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var data = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateModel>(data);
        bindingContext.Model = model;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Action in ApiController**

```
public IHttpActionResult Update(UpdateModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // this never happens :-(
    }
}
```

Related but for MVC not WebApi: [Custom model binding, model state, and data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820637/custom-model-binding-model-state-and-data-annotations)

Answer (score 1):

Validation through DataAnnotation was treated in Model Binder. If you use your own ModelBinder, you must explicit call validation over DataAnnotation in the ModelBinder - if you wish automatic validation over DA.